# Json string array without attributes transform XSLT

Tags: arrays, json, xslt, transform, ibm-datapower

As the tittle says, I need some help to figure out how to transform JSON array without attributes to XSL.

(1)Input:

```
{
  "Body": {
    "name": "jhon",
    "ids": ["a", "b"]
  }
}
```

(2) The expected output should have this structure.

```
{
  "name": "jhon",
  "ids": ["a", "b"]
}
```

I have tried to transform it like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="path" select="*/Body"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">{
        "name" : "<xsl:value-of select="$path/name"/>",
        "ids" : "<xsl:value-of select="$path/ids"/>"
    }
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the Datapower is not able to transform the json array [ids], instead it returns this message ***"An error occurred when processing the message***" and this output (3):

```
{
  "Body": {
    "Fault": {
      "faultcode": "",
      "faultactor": "",
      "detail": {
        "IntegrationError": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I remove "ids" field from request and transform XSL, it works ok. That's why I believe that I'm not transforming the array correctly.

Comment: Please edit your question and add (1) the input, (2) the expected output and (3) the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: Since XSLT 1.0 only handles XML, not JSON, there's presumably some JSON-to-XML conversion happening here before the XSLT transformation kicks in. It would be useful to show us that XML. Note that it's impossible for XML and JSON to have the same structure, they are different data models and there is no 1-to-1 correspondence between them.

Comment: The error you quote does not seem to be related to XSLT. It would probably be best to retag this question as `[ibm-datapower]`.

Comment: DataPower does have a built-in JSON to XML transformation format called JSONX, but you do not appear to be using it here, because if you were, none of your attempts would have worked, with or without arrays.  (JSONX is IBM's attempt at dealing with the differing data models that Michael is referring to.) How are you executing the XSL -- is it one step in a processing policy?  I suspect there's a step before your transform that is doing the JSON to XML conversion.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use for-each for id's check it online.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).